Image overlapping in css grid-template-areas div
I have 6 images that I want to align with grid-template-areas. The problem is when I set one image to cover a bigger grid-area, the next image does not move to the next grid area but overlaps the bigger image. css as below.
.image-gallery{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 40rem;
    grid-gap:1.5rem;
    grid-template-areas:
                'img-1 img-2 img-3'
                'img-4 img-5 img-3'
                'img-6 img-6 img-6'
           


 
              
               
}

.img-1{

    grid-area: img-1;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/nyungu.jpg");

}

.img-2{
    
    grid-area: img-2;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/itimu.jpeg");

}

.img-3{
    min-height: 71.5rem;
    grid-area: img-3;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/ndome2.jpeg");

}

.img-4{
  
    grid-area: img-4;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/kiondo.jpeg");
    
}
.img-5{
   
    grid-area: img-5;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/mwatu.jpeg");

}

.img-6{
   
    min-height: 40rem;
    grid-area: img-6;
    background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/njora.jpeg");

}

Now one img-6 goes to the place I have already put img-3. below is the html.
       <div class="image-gallery">   


            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/nyungu.jpg" class="img-1">1
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">1</i> 
                    
                </a>

                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                
            </div>
            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/itimu.jpeg" class="img-2">2
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">2</i> 
                </a>
                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            </div>
            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/ndome2.jpeg" class="img-3">3
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">3</i> 
                </a>
                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, 
                    iusto? Veritatis quibusdam, modi provident impedit laboriosam, suscipit voluptatibus, 
                   .</p>
            </div>
            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/kiondo.jpeg" class="img-4">4
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">4</i> 
                </a>
                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            </div>
            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/mwatu.jpeg" class="img-5">5
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">5</i> 
                </a>
                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti.</p>
            </div>
            <div  >
                <a href="./gallery/artefacts/njora.jpeg" class="img-6">6
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">6</i> 
                </a>
                <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti.</p>
            </div>      

        </div>

Kindly assist me solve the above problem . note img-3 is height is taller than all the other images.
I tried the minmax for grid height to see if it would adjust but the result was now all img-6 were pushed downwards leaving and empy space

I resolved the problem, the issues was I was assigning the class on a tag to the grid area instead of assigned the class from div to the grid area

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Add object fit to image property.


.image-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 40rem;
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: 'img-1 img-2 img-3' 'img-4 img-5 img-3' 'img-6 img-6 img-6'
}

.img-1 {
  grid-area: img-1;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/nyungu.jpg");
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-2 {
  grid-area: img-2;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/itimu.jpeg");
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-3 {
  min-height: 71.5rem;
  grid-area: img-3;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/ndome2.jpeg");
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-4 {
  grid-area: img-4;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/kiondo.jpeg");
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-5 {
  grid-area: img-5;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/mwatu.jpeg");
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-6 {
  min-height: 40rem;
  grid-area: img-6;
  background-image: url("./gallery/artefacts/njora.jpeg");
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="image-gallery">


  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/nyungu.jpg" class="img-1">1
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">1</i> 
                    
                </a>

    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/itimu.jpeg" class="img-2">2
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">2</i> 
                </a>
    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/ndome2.jpeg" class="img-3">3
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">3</i> 
                </a>
    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, iusto? Veritatis quibusdam, modi provident impedit laboriosam, suscipit voluptatibus, .
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/kiondo.jpeg" class="img-4">4
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">4</i> 
                </a>
    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/mwatu.jpeg" class="img-5">5
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">5</i> 
                </a>
    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="./gallery/artefacts/njora.jpeg" class="img-6">6
                    <i class="icon ion-md-expand">6</i> 
                </a>
    <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti.</p>
  </div>

</div>



